# How would I auto-explore a Minecraft world for Dynmap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft server that is using a custom map of the earth, and I have set up Dynmap for it. Although no matter what I try, the only land that shows up on dynmap is the land that I have physically loaded in. I want to be able to load in the map automatically so it shows up in dynmap. I have tried using BlueCommander's chunk pre-generator that teleports me around to load in chunks, but it doesn't seem to have worked. Is there any other way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to explore the entire world, so the chunks are generated and are accessible by dynmap (BlueCommander's AFK world chunk generator is one way).

Then, you need to run the following command to make dynmap generate the map for areas with no players:

```
/dynmap fullrender
```

Please note that the command will cause extreme lag and probably will kick all of the players, so avoid executing it when there are users on the server.

Comment: The problem I have with the AFK chunk generator is that it takes an extremely long time. When I look at the estimated time, it is giving me numbers around 600+ hours which is around a month. I was wondering if there was any faster way of loadding in those chunks. Also quick question, if a custom map is used aren't the chunks already generated or do I have to go and generate them manually by exploring?

Comment: There is no way to generate them quicker because the game needs some time to do the chunk generation. You can try to add more players to generate the terrain quicker.

Comment: For the custom maps, they might have custom generators (common) or the map is ready to explore. The downside of the later is that you might need to download a large file with the map information.

Comment: Yeah right now I downloaded and am using a map of the earth if that is what you mean.

Comment: Try to open the map with MCEdit and see if all of the chunks are generated. If they are not, your only option is the AFK Chunk Generator.

Comment: I ended up setting up an autohotkey that flies in rows along the world in spectator mode, and changed the gamerule to allow spectators to generate chunks. This I found was much more efficient than the teleport method as it finished in one day, and there were a few holes so I am running it a few more times. I just had it fly straight, and then use a tp command thay just changed the orientation of the player instead of using any stupid complicated MouseEvent things. It seems to be working very well, thanks for the suggestions.